# Hadoop dfs not starting

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, hdfs, ubuntu-14.04

**start-dfs.sh doesn't start neither namenode nor datanode**

Before I had a perfectly working single cluster setup, but afterward I tried to login to the user account for which hadoop was setup. Somehow unity failed during login and I was forced to force shutdown my system (didn't know how to logout). After this the namenode and the datanode don't startup.

**This is the exception I get in the log files (it's the same for both namenode and datanode):**
`2014-11-18 23:39:58,216 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2014-11-18 23:40:13,929 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Exception in secureMain
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/exception/NestableRuntimeException 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableRuntimeException`

**Following are the contents of /etc/hosts/:**

`127.0.0.1  localhost
127.0.1.1   saswat-Inspiron-N5010
10.42.0.1 masterSas
10.42.0.39 slavek
10.42.0.70 slaveS
10.42.0.86 slaveA`

the slaves and master aliases are for multinode setup.

Comment: If you don't have any needed data in the system, one option is to try to reformat the namenode and see what happens. I've never seen such error message myself so can't help you much, sorry.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen Thanks for your response, but I have already tried that and it didn't work. 
One thing I don't get is that a system may not have apache commons libraries at all and hadoop itself has all these libraries in it's share and they are referenced as well, hence my confusion